# Looking for a way to loop through Sass animations

Tags: loops, sass

Could someone help convert the following functionality into a Sass loop? I imagine it's pretty self explanatory:

Many thanks in advance

```
@keyframes slideIn {
    from {opacity:0;transform:translateX(-20px);}
    to {opacity:1;transform:translateX(0px);}
  }  
  &:nth-child(1) {
    animation:slideIn .5s;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    animation:slideIn 1s;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    animation:slideIn 1.5s;
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    animation:slideIn 2s;
  }
  &:nth-child(5) {
    animation:slideIn 2.5s;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, you can use a @for loop.

```
@keyframes slideIn {
  from {opacity:0;transform:translateX(-20px);}
  to {opacity:1;transform:translateX(0px);}
} 

@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .class {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation: slideIn ($i * 0.5) + s
    }
  }
}
```

which compiles to

```
@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
.class:nth-child(1) {
  animation: slideIn 0.5s;
}

.class:nth-child(2) {
  animation: slideIn 1s;
}

.class:nth-child(3) {
  animation: slideIn 1.5s;
}

.class:nth-child(4) {
  animation: slideIn 2s;
}

.class:nth-child(5) {
  animation: slideIn 2.5s;
}
```

Comment: This looks great... what if didn't want to restrict to 5 items, but wanted infinity? thanks